# Including common section in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I'm trying to create a common section to all stages in my CI/CD pipeline. This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: debian:bullseye

default:
  tags:
    - qa

stages:
  - build_vm

.common:
    script:
    - echo "######################## Installing stuff ########################"
    - export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    - apt-get update
    - |
      apt-get install -qy \
        ca-certificates \
        git \
        jq \
        make \
        nmap \
        openssh-client \
        python3 \
    - make VERBOSE=true "$MAKEFILE_TARGET"


build_vm:
  before_script:
    - export PYTHONPATH="$CI_PROJECT_DIR":$PYTHONPATH
  variables:
    MAKEFILE_TARGET: build_vm
  stage: build_vm
  extends: .common
  script:
    - echo "build_vm $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
    - make VERBOSE=true "$MAKEFILE_TARGET"
```

However, the `.common` section is not included during job runs.

To test if it's running I included using `make` (with my `Makefile` being present in the project of course) in `build_vm` and the pipeline job complains:

```
/bin/bash: line 170: make: command not found
```

So clearly the `.common` stage hasn't run (because it didn't install `make` as it would have).

Why is this section not included? It should be easy enough, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have extended will cause the `build_vm` script section override the `.common` script section.

Here is the right way to do this using `!reference`

```
image: debian:bullseye

default:
  tags:
    - qa

stages:
  - build_vm

.common:
    script:
    - echo "######################## Installing stuff ########################"
    - export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    - apt-get update
    - |
      apt-get install -qy \
        ca-certificates \
        git \
        jq \
        make \
        nmap \
        openssh-client \
        python3 \
    - make VERBOSE=true "$MAKEFILE_TARGET"


build_vm:
  before_script:
    - export PYTHONPATH="$CI_PROJECT_DIR":$PYTHONPATH
  variables:
    MAKEFILE_TARGET: build_vm
  stage: build_vm
  script:
    - !reference [.common, script]
    - echo "build_vm $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
    - make VERBOSE=true "$MAKEFILE_TARGET"
```